# How to configure / consume a web service in BizTalk 2013

Tags: web-services, web, service, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I need some help in integrating web services into Biztalk 2013

Scenario is, we have several existing Web services which need to be configured in BizTalk 2013. From now onwards the consumer will access the webservices from Biztalk in stead of original URl.

Can anyone share a step-by-step guide for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Steef -Jan Wiggers answers a similar question, please have a look , [Using services in BizTalk](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5bfe2015-813a-4910-9be9-05a2c81718f5/using-services-in-biztalk?forum=biztalkgeneral)

Although the .xsd files imported by Add Service is added as a schema and set to BtsCompile, there are some limitations such as:

Add Service Reference will add the client proxy, which isn't needed in a BizTalk project (and which might 'tempt' your devs to do silly things like using this proxy from a Custom assembly)
Service Reference makes a mess of importing complicated WSDL (e.g. with Generics or dependencies on other Schemas), See [Considerations when consuming Web Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561724%28BTS.70%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
Using the **Add Generated Items wizard** does extra work for you:

Adds in a Port Type for accessing the service, already preconfigured for the correct message types. Note however that it adds the Port type to a dummy .odx - i.e. don't delete the odx until you've moved the Port type elsewhere.
Allow you to create the Send Port bindings at the same time.
One thing I would recommend with the Wizard, is to create a folder for the WCF reference and always import all the artifacts into the folder (i.e. don't do the usual separation of Schemas from Ports and leave the dummy .odx there as well). This way, if you need to regenerate the items, just delete everything in the folder and start again (sadly, the wizard doesn't have a Update Service Reference equivalent.

Also note that if you do move the generated Schemas and Port Types into a separate assembly, that you will need to change the type modifier access to Public (it is internal by default)